# How to use attrs required dependent on a fields many2one in openerp?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

I have two class:

```
class hr_holidays(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'hr.holidays'
    _columns = {
        'holiday_status_id': fields.many2one("hr.holidays.status", "Loại nghỉ", required=True,readonly=True, states={'draft':[('readonly',False)], 'confirm':[('readonly',False)]}, track_visibility='onchange'),
        'cost': fields.float('Cost', track_visibility='onchange'),
        }
class hr_holidays_status(osv.osv):
    _name = "hr.holidays.status"
    _columns = {
        'is_cost': fields.boolean('Cost'),
        }
```

Now, I write in file .xml of `hr_holidays`  with '`cost`' have attribute `required` when  `is_cost` of `hr.holidays.status` = True

```
<field name="cost" attrs="{'required':[('is_cost','=',True)]}"/>
```

But Odoo not understand `is_cost` and error.
I hope to get your help. Thank you very much. 
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for using `is_cost` in hr.holidays.

1. **Create a relate  field** is_cost in the `'hr.holidays'` with the `holiday_status_id`.
2. **Define** this field in view.
3. then you can use in attrs.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I was using it and have a problem occurs is fileds cost is entered directly on the form fields. If using related, after press Save, the new value is loaded. So, want to enter the cost, we must click Edit to add a value there. Very inconvenient for user. 
I do not know any other way, so expect help from you

Comment: sorry but i ma unable to understand the scenario your are facing :"If using related, after press Save, the new value is loaded. So, want to enter the cost, we must click Edit to add a value there", just post a  new question with the code(.py and .xml) you have done so far , i will try to fix it

Comment: Thank you for giving me an idea. I have solved your problems. 
1. Create 1 fields 'is_cost' in 'hr.holidays'. This fields invisible.
2. Write def onchange_holiday_status_id(holiday_status_id). Get value 'is_cost'. 
3. <field name="cost" attrs="{'required':[('is_cost','=',True)]}"/>